# How to copy one register to another?

Tags: evil, registers

In vim `:let @"=@*` will *copy* the content of`*` register to the `"` register. How can it be done with evil?

Answer (score 1):

This code should do that.

```lisp
(set-register ?" (get-register ?*))
```

If you want that in a command:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (set-register ?" (get-register ?*)))
```

Or if you want a command that reads the register names:

```lisp
(defun copy-register-to-register (from to)
  (interactive
   (list (register-read-with-preview "From register: ")
         (register-read-with-preview "To register: ")))
  (set-register to (get-register from)))
```

(Emacs registers are not particular to Evil, so Evil is, I think irrelevant to your question. Evil may be how you interact with registers, but setting them with Elisp should independent of Evil.)

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(evil-set-register ?\" (evil-get-register ?*))
```

Comment: Could you say something about how these versions are in relation to than the standard emacs functions?  Should they be preferred?